# How to fix error in the react-barcode-qrcode-scanner component?

Tags: reactjs, next.js13, dynamsoft

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyiNl.png)

I am using react-barcode-qrcode-scanner component to get the barcode and qrcode data. But it makes this error. How to fix it?

This is the source code of react-barcode-qrcode-scanner. The error occurs in the useEffect part. I am not sure why does it happens. It is the sample code of react-barcode-qrcode-scanner component.

```html
import { BarcodeReader, TextResult } from 'dynamsoft-javascript-barcode';
import React from 'react';
import { CameraProps, VisionCamera } from 'react-vision-camera';

export interface ScannerProps extends CameraProps{
  runtimeSettings?: string;
  license?: string;
  engineResourcePath?: string;
  interval?:number;
  drawOverlay?: boolean;
  onInitialized?: (reader:BarcodeReader) => void;
  onScanned?: (results:TextResult[]) => void;
  onClicked?: (result:TextResult) => void;
}

const QRBarcodeScanner = (props:ScannerProps): React.ReactElement => {
  const interval = React.useRef(null);
  const camera = React.useRef(null);
  const reader = React.useRef(null);
  const mounted = React.useRef(false);
  const decoding = React.useRef(false);
  const [viewBox, setViewBox] = React.useState("0 0 1280 720");
  const [barcodeResults, setBarcodeResults] = React.useState([] as TextResult[]);
  
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    const init = async () => {
      if (props.license) {
        BarcodeReader.license = props.license;
      }else{
        BarcodeReader.license = "DLS2eyJoYW5kc2hha2VDb2RlIjoiMjAwMDAxLTE2NDk4Mjk3OTI2MzUiLCJvcmdhbml6YXRpb25JRCI6IjIwMDAwMSIsInNlc3Npb25QYXNzd29yZCI6IndTcGR6Vm05WDJrcEQ5YUoifQ=="; // public trial license
      }
      if (props.engineResourcePath) {
        BarcodeReader.engineResourcePath = props.engineResourcePath;
      }else{
        BarcodeReader.engineResourcePath = "https://unpkg.com/dynamsoft-javascript-barcode@latest/dist/";
      }
      
      reader.current = await BarcodeReader.createInstance();
      
      if (props.runtimeSettings) {
        await (reader.current as BarcodeReader).initRuntimeSettingsWithString(props.runtimeSettings);
      }
      if (props.onInitialized) {
        props.onInitialized(reader.current);
      }
    }
    init();
    mounted.current = true;
  },[])

  React.useEffect(()=>{
    if (props.runtimeSettings && reader.current) {
      (reader.current as BarcodeReader).initRuntimeSettingsWithString(props.runtimeSettings);
    }
  },[props.runtimeSettings])

  const startScanning = () => {
    const decode = async () => {
      if (decoding.current === false && reader.current && camera.current) {
        decoding.current = true;
        const results = await reader.current.decode(camera.current);
        setBarcodeResults(results);
        if (props.onScanned) {
          props.onScanned(results);
        }
        decoding.current = false;
      }
    }
    if (props.interval) {
      interval.current = setInterval(decode,props.interval);
    }else{
      interval.current = setInterval(decode,40);
    }
    
  }

  const stopScanning = () => {
    clearInterval(interval.current);
  }

  const onOpened = (cam:HTMLVideoElement,camLbl:string) => {
    camera.current = cam;
    setViewBox("0 0 "+cam.videoWidth+" "+cam.videoHeight);
    startScanning();
    if (props.onOpened) {
      props.onOpened(cam,camLbl);
    }
  }

  const onClosed = () => {
    stopScanning();
    if (props.onClosed) {
      props.onClosed();
    }
  }

  const onPolygonClicked = (result:TextResult) => {
    if (props.onClicked) {
      props.onClicked(result);
    }
  }

  const getPointsData = (result:TextResult) => {
    const lr = result.localizationResult;
    let pointsData = lr.x1+","+lr.y1 + " ";
    pointsData = pointsData+ lr.x2+","+lr.y2 + " ";
    pointsData = pointsData+ lr.x3+","+lr.y3 + " ";
    pointsData = pointsData+ lr.x4+","+lr.y4;
    return pointsData;
  }
  
  return (
    <VisionCamera
      isActive={props.isActive}
      isPause={props.isPause}
      facingMode={props.facingMode}
      desiredCamera={props.desiredCamera}
      desiredResolution={props.desiredResolution}
      onOpened={onOpened}
      onClosed={onClosed}
      onDeviceListLoaded={props.onDeviceListLoaded}
    >
      {props.children}
      {renderSVGOverlay()}
    </VisionCamera>
  )
}

export default QRBarcodeScanner;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether wasm is loaded before setting the license and engine resources path:

```js
 if (BarcodeReader.isWasmLoaded() === false) {
    if (props.license) {
      BarcodeReader.license = props.license;
    }else{
      BarcodeReader.license = "DLS2eyJoYW5kc2hha2VDb2RlIjoiMjAwMDAxLTE2NDk4Mjk3OTI2MzUiLCJvcmdhbml6YXRpb25JRCI6IjIwMDAwMSIsInNlc3Npb25QYXNzd29yZCI6IndTcGR6Vm05WDJrcEQ5YUoifQ=="; // public trial license
    }
    if (props.engineResourcePath) {
      BarcodeReader.engineResourcePath = props.engineResourcePath;
    }else{
      BarcodeReader.engineResourcePath = "https://unpkg.com/dynamsoft-javascript-barcode@latest/dist/";
    }
  }
```

Or use the version 0.1.3 which has this fixed.